# What does this mean?

Tags: logical-deduction, mathematics, number-sequence, enigmatic-puzzle

**What is the magic word?**

> 011021042021011012012032012032014

**Clues (Read, in order, one and re-think the problem):**

> 1. Five letter word
> 2. 'A' equals 011051
> 3. Binary (Eight digit per)
> 4. Compressed message (Zero - Show, One - Hide)
> 5. ASCII Letters

**If you have the answer:**

> Say the word = *+1 for you*
>
> Say the word and with the same method say what 02301102103102 means = *Best Answer*

Comment: Is this case sensitive? Do the codes for 'A' and 'a' differ?

Comment: Yes, it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Aswer: Hello :D

> This is simply the binary ASCII stream encoded as a `0` followed by the count of consecutive zeroes, then the count of consecutive ones, repeated for each group of zeroes and ones in the message.
>
>  Example:
>  `Test`
>  Is encoded in binary ASCII as:
>  `01010100 01100101 01110011 01110100`
>  This is split into groups of zeroes followed by ones:
>  `01 01 01 00011 001 01 0111 0011 0111 01 00`
>  Each group is then converted to a `0`, followed by the number of zeroes, followed by the number of ones:
>  `011 011 011 032 021 011 013 022 013 011 02`
>  The result is concatenated to produce the final string:
>  `01101101103202101101302201301102`

01105101201203201204106301103201104202101102106401102202101101302102201401202101101302202106204101302102202101102106301101101201302201302202101101203201202101101302201302201204101302102402102101204106201201101204101201101201202101101302202106202202201401302103106302201201401201201101202101102106301301204101302201301103202101101202202301101101201204107103102203201201401201201101305302102202101101302201302201201102101201401201303103103101204106301103201104201401301101101202301201105106301103201104202101101402102106202103201402106201201101204101201101201202101102106201102101301104106204102106203102201102101301104106202101101204101302201201102101202101101302103106301103201402106201101201202101101202101101306106301103302102204101203201201101202106201401202203106201401201302202101102102301302202106305201401302201201102101301103201102101201401201302202101102106301301201104202101101201303106305204101302102302201201102101201302202302106301103201104202101102106201201101202101101302201302201204101202301202101102106201201101204101201302301101101204101201203201203402102101301

The real magic word is of course 011011052012032021011012041013022012021011

Comment: Okey the real magic word is 011011052012032021011012041013022012021011, :P

Comment: Do you think you could add some translation? Currently, this only communicates with those that bother to decode it.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The answer is in the spoiler box, the encoded message is just there for you to itch to know what says.

Comment: You have produced an algorithm in the spoiler box. I see no plain decoded text.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I wouldn't have gotten an accepted answer if I didn't provide the decoded message. It is there, but it was hard to get through the SE sanitation bot.

Comment: I'm asking you to improve your answer for the benefit of the community, not because I think you didn't answer correctly. Just improve your answer, please.

Comment: A few quick [encoder](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P6SwOtMoySIkNbquVjU1wSDN1kg/TRsonlpcAgA "CJam – Try It Online") and [decoder](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9BYvzqz2KouNTU8TbWuVjW1zkLfKC3JKvn/fwNDQygyNjIwgrCNDYyMQCSQbQQA "CJam – Try It Online") scripts for your convenience.

Comment: I think your message (the long one after the spoiler) has a typo. Shouldn't it be [this](https://tio.run/##HY6xDsIwEEN/xUJCDCBAnVgY@Ac2Fq7l0oYmuZBLVRUEv14Ciy1Z9pObO/l5Pj9etqoPZ7583ku@7s2x2pn1PJ@cQ@4YT07CCkqMIQRuWJXStIGnvsRGElQ8YyTNbAaHRSM@ptKyEhabgpCh7X6kCTf5r2AzCHVRJrWckAU9c0RO1PQQAwm8UkRRmwsFY8cBkZLa0P4/@d@JtjiFgZybtl8)?